# Typing an apostrophe in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, typography, smart-quotes

I have "Use Smart Quotes" enabled in Photoshop. I like it and want to keep it enabled. However, when I need an apostrophe, I get an opening (or in German typography: closing) Smart Quote instead *(see "wrong" in the picture)*.

[image]

Then what I usually do is look up "Apostrophe" in Wikipedia, copy it from there and paste it to Photoshop. *(I know I might also use Alt+0146, but I keep forgetting the combination every now and then.)*

Isn't there a way to quickly type the correct apostrophe in Photoshop? Like Ctrl+something?

Comment: So `Ctrl`+something is acceptable somehow but `Alt`+something is not..... I feel sorry for `Alt`

Comment: Haha, well, you know what I mean... :D I was thinking something like Ctrl+' or similar.

Comment: An apostrophe is not a quote mark & the system shouldn't treat it as such. An apostrophe mid-word shouldn't ever be auto-corrected to an open quote. Is it only Photoshop that's doing this, or is some other system tool doing it? We'd also need to know what OS, as I'm on Mac & cannot force this to break, no matter what I've tried. We probably need to know what version of Photoshop too.

Comment: It's only Photoshop. Word, for example, is (not always, but mostly) smart enough to do it correctly. I'm having the problem on both Windows 8.1 and Windows 10, with Photoshop CC 2015 (64 bit).
Are you saying, when you type "I'm" in Photoshop, it looks exactly like the "correct" part of my picture above???

Comment: Yes - it converts 'straight' to 'the right way up curly', example 2. It also gets everything right if I type 'I'd' or "I'd".

Comment: Wow, that's interesting, because my straight "apostrophes" are never ever converted into the correct ones - neither at the beginning of a word nor at the end nor in the middle. I shall try to install an English language pack and see how it behaves then.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is to type two diacritical marks (or  alternatively known as apostrophes) and then remove the wrong one. i.e. when you type two diacritical marks, you'll get this `‘’`. Now remove the first one and you will be left with only `’`.

Comment: Hmm, when I try that, I end up with: `I‘‘d`. Probably because I'm using Photoshop in German. :/ Dammit.

Comment: @Ginchen No idea about German. Btw if you type  `'I'd`, what do you get?  Hopefully this: `‘I’d`. if yes then you can remove the first mark to get  `I’d`. Another alternate way may be to use the font that has same marks for acute `’` and grave `‘` diacritics.  The font `Ebrima`, for example, has `'` for both `’` and  `‘` (if I am not mistaken)

Comment: I get `‚I‘d`, which is typographically correct in German. Too bad, your tip would have been a good enough solution for me!

Comment: @Ginchen Well then it seems that using *English Language Pack* for writing *English* is the solution you're looking for!

Comment: Hmm, yes, but apart from having to switch it often then, I have the same problem in German, too. For example when trying to write something like `Wie geht’s?`, it will become `Wie geht‘s?`, and your tip doesn't help there either, because it will yield either `‚‘` or `‘‘`. I start to believe that my Wikipedia technique may still be the easiest way... ^^